# Using dplyr in rstudio to get data from SNOWFLAKE

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have connected my rstudio to snowflake using odbc driver. Now, I am trying to get the data from snowflake using tbl and collect function. While I can see the correct numbers of colnames in local R, I am not seeing any observations (dim = 0 obs , 3 variables). I am using below codes in r to get the desired data from snowflake into r.

```r
myconn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "connect", Database = "LNR", Schema = "COMM")

db_data <- tbl(myconn, 'data') %>% filter(VAR1 == "XXX") %>% select(VAR1, VAR2, VAR3) %>% collect(). 

dim(db_data)
#0 obs , 3 variables
```

Are there any changes required in my codes to get correct observation along with columns I am selecting?

Comment: To add to Shawn's note, how would we know? What if your data has no cases where VAR1 == "XXX" ?

Comment: You could add  `show_query()` to the end of your pipeline instead of `collect()`. This will return the SQL that is getting generated by dplyr and give you a better idea of why it is not returning what your expecting.  Alternatively, if you have access the to Snowflake Web UI (Snowsight) you can check your query history, and see the same SQL that was generated

Answer (score 0):

I use the jdbc connection to Snowflake, so the connection bit might be slightly different.

But that seems to be working, and you just seem to be having trouble with the filter (you ended up with 0 rows), so I think I can give a suggestion.

You asked for changes you could make to the code... I would do something to help check the levels in that variable you are filtering on.

For example:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

myconn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "connect", Database = "LNR", Schema = "COMM")

db_data_initial <- tbl(myconn, 'data') 

observed_var1_values <- db_data_initial %>% 
  select(VAR1) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  pull()
```

I'm assuming "XXX" was just a placeholder.  But whatever it is you are looking to filter on, you should be sure that value appears in "VAR1".   If not, that would certainly cause you to get back a result with 0 rows after the filter.

If after you run this, you realize that the value is capitalized differently, and is really "XxX", you can then continue with basically the same code you proposed, but with the correct spelling.

```
db_data <- db_data_initial %>%
   filter(VAR1 == "XxX") %>% 
   select(VAR1, VAR2, VAR3) %>% 
   collect()
```